# Finding a Target node on Dijkstra’s Algorithm with Priority Queues in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this implementation of a graph using adjacency lists and I want to make it work with Dijkstra’s Algorithm. I don't know whether I'm brain dead or not but I can't think of a way to make the priority queue version find the shortest path from the source to the start. I've read the wikipedia page but it just isn't enough. Can anybody help?!

```
class Vertex:
def __init__(self,key):
    self.id = key
    self.connectedTo = {}

def addNeighbor(self,nbr,weight=0):
    self.connectedTo[nbr] = weight

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

def getConnections(self):
    return self.connectedTo.keys()

def getId(self):
    return self.id

def getWeight(self,nbr):
    return self.connectedTo[nbr]

class Graph:
def __init__(self):
    self.vertList = {}
    self.numVertices = 0

def addVertex(self,key):
    self.numVertices = self.numVertices + 1
    newVertex = Vertex(key)
    self.vertList[key] = newVertex
    return newVertex

def getVertex(self,n):
    if n in self.vertList:
        return self.vertList[n]
    else:
        return None

def __contains__(self,n):
    return n in self.vertList

def addEdge(self,f,t,cost=0):
    if f not in self.vertList:
        nv = self.addVertex(f)
    if t not in self.vertList:
        nv = self.addVertex(t)
    self.vertList[f].addNeighbor(self.vertList[t], cost)

def getVertices(self):
    return self.vertList.keys()

def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.vertList.values())

def main(self, input1):
            """
            Automates the insertion process
            """
            try:
                if input1 is None:
                    ans=True
                    while ans != False:
                        print ("""
                        1.Insert nodes
                        2.Print representation
                        3.Exit
                        """)
                        ans=input("What would you like to do?")
                        if ans=="1":
                            rfilename = input("Enter file to read: ")
                            f = open(rfilename) #file 1
                            linelist = list(f) #linelist is a list with each member corresponding to one line in the txt file
                            for i in range(len(linelist)): #inserts all vertexes
                                line = linelist[i].split()
                                self.addVertex(line[0])
                            for i in range(len(linelist)): #inserts all edges
                                line = linelist[i].split()
                                self.addEdge(line[0], line[1], int(line[2]))
                        elif ans=="2":
                            for v in self:
                                for w in v.getConnections():
                                    print("( %s to %s, %s)" % (v.getId(), w.getId(), v.getWeight(w)))
                        elif ans=="3":
                            ans = False

            except(FileNotFoundError):
                        print("File not found")

def dijkstra(self,start):
    pq = PriorityQueue()
    start.setDistance(0)
    pq.insert([(v.getDistance(),v) for v in self])
    while not pq.is_empty():
        currentVert = pq.remove()
        for nextVert in currentVert.getConnections():
            newDist = currentVert.getDistance() + currentVert.getWeight(nextVert)
            if newDist < nextVert.getDistance():
                nextVert.setDistance( newDist )
                nextVert.setPred(currentVert)
                pq.decreaseKey(nextVert,newDist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `Python Algorithms` book with "Magnus Lie Hetland" You can do it elegant with [`heapg`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#module-heapq) module . This module provides an implementation of the heap queue algorithm, also known as the priority queue algorithm.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
def dijkstra(G, s):
    D, P, Q, S = {s:0}, {}, [(0,s)], set()    #Est., tree, queue, visited
    while Q:                                  #Still unprocessed nodes?
        _, u = heappop(Q)                     #Node with lowest estimate
        if u in S: continue                   #Already visited? Skip it
            S.add(u)                          #We've visited it now
            for v in G[u]:                    #Go through all its neighbors
                relax(G, u, v, D, P)          #Relax the out-edge
                heappush(Q, (D[v], v))        #Add to queue, w/est. as pri
    return D, P                               #Final D and P returned
```

`Dijkstra’s algorithm` may be similar to Prim’s (with another set of priorities for the queue), but it is
also closely related to another old favorite: `BFS`.

Comment: How could I change this to include stopping at a target?